# airflow does not start at a specific time

Tags: cron, timezone, airflow, schedule

I have a DAG, which has a cron configuration in its schedule, but it always starts at midnight America / Guatemala, I share part of my code, what I would like is for it to start at 9 am Guatemala, the airflow is as aws service , so I don't have a lot of driving options, Thank you for your support, It is an amazon cloud service, this is the configuration in utc, I only have the UI in America / Guatemala time zone

```
###code

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pendulum
import pytz
import time
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'David Martinez',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'is_paused_upon_creation': False
    }   


dag=DAG(
        'test_excnt',
        description='JOB GLUE',
        start_date=  datetime(2021, 6, 12, tzinfo=pendulum.timezone('America/Guatemala')),
     schedule_interval='0 9 * * *',
        default_args=default_args,
        max_active_runs=1,
        catchup=True)




t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='1.1',
    bash_command="echo {{next_execution_date.in_timezone('America/Guatemala') }}",
    dag=dag
    # wait_for_downstream=True
    )

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='2',
    bash_command="echo {{execution_date.in_timezone('America/Guatemala') }}",
    dag=dag
    # wait_for_downstream=True
)

t1>>t2
```

Comment: Have you configured proper `default_timezone` in our airflow config?

Comment: It is an amazon cloud service, this is the configuration in utc, I only have the UI in America / Guatemala time zone